# regular expression to remove part of string

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to instert an integer into a form.  Users are asked to input there promo number which is in the format 12.2-9999.  I only want to insert 9999 into the column in my database but I am getting -9999 in the columns.  I am not sure if I should use preg_replace or something else here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode), like so:

```
list( , $promo) = explode( '-', '12.2-9999');
```

Now `$promo` will contain `9999`.

Answer (score 2):

The following regular expression will check for the last `-` and capture the digits to the end (which as per the example is `9999`):

```
/-(\d+)$/
```

Comment: thanks for this are you able to put the regex to show everything before the -?  I have tried multiple combinations using the ^ etc but haven't had any luck